# what does drew imply in the following

Tags: word-choice

Consider the following:

> She *drew* the curtains.

What does drew mean here? Does it mean that she closed or opened the curtains? According to *American English Thesaurus*, draw could imply both *open* and *close*.

> 4. she drew the curtains: close, shut, lower; open, part, pull back, pull open, fling open, raise.

If it implies *close*, what will be the opposite of *drew*? I am looking for something better than *open*.

Comment: Noah, your question reminds me of [this one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29805/how-does-a-word-come-to-have-two-completely-opposite-meanings) (not a duplicate, but you might find that interesting reading nonetheless).  To answer your question, the opposite of _drew_ would be _drew_, but you'd simply provide context: i.e., "She drew the curtains open," or "She drew the curtains shut" (unless it's [Amelia Bedelia](http://www.epinions.com/content_234579594884?sb=1), who simply _drew the curtains_).

Comment: In Hindi, the word *kal* means both "tomorrow" and "yesterday" :)

Comment: Perhaps she's an artist?

Comment: @aetheria: No, she's more of a [literalist](http://www.kidsreads.com/reviews/series/amelia-bedelia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it implies "open" or "close". *Draw* simply means *pull* (the same as "draw water from a well").

Whether it's opening or closing in the case of curtains can only be inferred from context.

Comment: That example comes straight from the dictionary.

Comment: And it's a perfectly correct use of the word. The "close, shut, lower; open, part, pull back, pull open, fling open, raise" indicates that *drew* could mean all of those things, and which applies can only be gleaned from context.

Comment: And apparently I clicked that little tick.