# Is there a better word than "colorizable"?

Tags: word-choice

In part of the software my company develops, the user is presented with a list of black-and-white images. The user can select one of these images and then can select a color for it, changing it from black and white to the color they selected.

We are currently calling these “Colorizable Images”, as opposed to the alternative list of “Existing Color” images. But I am not sure that *colorizable* is a real word and am concerned people may not understand.

Is there a better term for something for which one can change the color of? We considered *colorable* but [the definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/colorable) seemed completely wrong.

An example might help. The user will see:

[image: a black and white image]

And when they choose to colorize that blue, they get:

[image: a blue and white image]

Comment: If you spelled "color" as "colour", then "colourable" might work. ;)

Comment: Sorry, as much as I try I can't bring my fingers to type that word ;)

Comment: In Britain, is it *colourisable* ???

Comment: I don't think that "colorizable" is going to confuse your audience. If need be, you could consider hyphenating it as "colorize-able". I suspect that "paintable" suffers from the same issues as "tintable". That said, why are you not calling them "Greyscale images"?

Comment: @coleopterist Thanks. FYI they're not greyscale. They're literally black images over transparent backgrounds, and when they get colorized, they become E.G. red, blue, yellow, etc. Think of a stamp... Just added an example

Comment: @GEdgar: I imagine they'd use *colourable* because the spelling is different from the spelling of *colorable* (the definition found by OP for *colorable* has nothing to do with colouring things).

Comment: A few dictionaries do have a second definition of colorable to mean what you want it to mean, like [this one](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/colorable?r=66), and one of the sources cited [here](http://www.wordnik.com/words/colorable). Interesting what else that word can mean, though.

Comment: @J.R. I know!!! How can it simultaneously mean *Meant to deceive; not genuine* **and** *Seemingly true or genuine; plausible*!? *Head explodes*

Comment: Looks to me like they merely colored it.

Comment: @tchrist: I think the OP wants a single word to describe something that is capable of being coloured.

Comment: @tchrist  FrustratedWithFormsDesigner said it exactly. Yes, I did color the image. I can only color some images, and some can't be colored. What do I call the images which can be colored?

Comment: What you just said.

Comment: That's going to be an awfully large tab name, **Images which can be colored**

Comment: *Re-colorable* or *recolorable* might do; also, would *uncolored* mislead?

Comment: @Josh: For more good reading about words that have contradictory meanings, visit [#29805](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29805/how-does-a-word-come-to-have-two-completely-opposite-meanings).

Comment: I'm with @jwpat7. *Recolorable* and *recolor* are widely used words in graphics.

Comment: Just as an aside, *colorize* is a fun word that shows the "American vs British" spellings of *color* and *-ize* are not so cut-and-dried as you might expect. All of combinations are used in the wild: [*colorize*, *colourise*, *colourize*, and even the odd *colorise*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/colorize)! (-:

Comment: @jwpat7 I like recolorable! Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given that *[colorize](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/colorize)* is a verb that I've seen used in graphics editing software to apply color to greyscale images, and *-able* is a general English suffix meaning that something is capable of being done, I'd say that *colorizable* sounds like a perfectly good word to use.

Comment: Thanks, that was my thinking, but I wasn't sure and wanted to run it past others...

Answer (score 8):

Why not simply use "customizable colour" or "custom coloured" images?

Do you need a single word?

Comment: I like "Custom Colored" images!

Answer (score 6):

"Colorizable" sounds awkwardly long. I would personally go for the simpler, "*Colorable*", or "*Ready-to-color*".

Depending on the context though you might be able to stretch out and use something like "Customizable" or call the images "Templates".

Comment: "Colorable"/"ready-to-color" suggest that you would be filling them in with color.

Answer (score 1):

What about coining a phrase such as *hue-shift* images? If you need to have the capable part emphasized, you could say *hue-shiftable*, but I like the simpler form.

If you are wed to the word *color* you could use *color-shift* or *color-shiftable*.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *any-color images* could work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid *colorable*, then *[tintable](http://www.wordnik.com/words/tintable)* is what you’re looking for.

Comment: No, it's way more than [tinting](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tint). We're not coloring *slightly*, we're completely replacing the color.

Comment: It’s going to depend on your audience. Despite that definition, *tinting* does not necessarily connote “slightly”. Follow the link and check out the examples of usage on the right.

Comment: Our audience is graphic designers. They'll complain about "tinting"... I know them too well :-)

Comment: Ouch. That they will. I concede defeat.

Comment: Sorry! I appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 0):

This may be way off base, but what about calling them "**line drawings**"? Or "**line drawn images**"?

Comment: Sorry, my example was confusing. *This* example is a line drawing but not all of them are...

Comment: Right, so the user can change the actual black of the image to a colour? Got it. Line drawings wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop experts would say "overlayable".

Comment: I cannot do anything if photoshop experts woud say "overlayable" in situations like that!

Answer (score 0):

You could call these "Open color images" and "Closed color images". Otherwise, colorizable fits too since "Colorizable images" are images that can be colorized, which is the case.

Answer (score -1):

*Colormorph* is a more accurate descriptor and might appeal to techie consumers.

Comment: This answer is extremely short. It could be improved by citing relevant facts, references, or specific expertise which support the answer, or by going into more detail: the how and the why of the answer.

Answer (score -2):

i think rephrase altogether to shift the focus off the images having some capability. inanimate objects don't really have capabilities. put the focus on the user having the action available.
"images for coloring by user", "the user introduces color to the black and white images"

Comment: That's a long tab / button name. I am looking for an adjective.

Comment: how many pixels do we have to work with?