# Words that mean the exact opposite to themselves

Tags: meaning, single-word-requests, antonyms

As I'm sure everyone is now aware, [the OED has now acknowledged that "literally" can be used to mean both "figuratively" AND "actually"](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-23729570) -- two words with the opposite definition. It got me wondering:

Are there any other words in the English language that can mean the opposite to itself?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does a word come to have two completely opposite meanings?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29805/) which deals with *how* this situation can arise. There's also [Can anyone provide me with a list of English words that are their own antonyms?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1820/) which has actual lists (and links to more lists! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That question is asking how such words come to exist.

Comment: Personally I think both your question *and* the second one that I just added to my previous comment are Off Topic "list requests". But I won't bother closevoting since I've no doubt I'd be overruled by others anyway.

Comment: Clip can mean "to attach" and "to cut off"

Comment: Wait a second. The article says the OED has added the "metaphorical usage." Nowhere does it mention the "figurative sense." Equating a person with a real, actual animal ("Owen was literally a greyhound.") is a metaphor. The whole sentence is a lie (though a poetic one), and in it the word _literally_ means _actually, factually, genuinely, veritably._ So, you've offered a bad example. The question itself is a good one, though, but it's been asked before.

Comment: Self-reflexive antonym

Comment: @TaliaFord You're wrong, I'm afraid: http://www.salon.com/2013/08/22/according_to_the_dictionary_literally_now_also_means_figuratively_newscred/

Answer (score 0):

With all due respect to the OED, *literally* meaning "figuratively" is just wrong. But there are plenty of English words that do have contradictory meanings, with "cleave" being a famous example meaning both "divide" and "unite."

Comment: The OED didn't add the meaning "figuratively"; they, simply, said that the word _literally_ may be used to tell lies that amount to a metaphor, thus be used "metaphorically." That's way different from saying, "_literally_ can also mean _figuratively_."

Comment: Sorry, just took the original poster at their word without checking the source.

Comment: I know; I was just clarifying for the future readers.

Comment: @TaliaFord My head literally exploded reading your comment.

Comment: (Note: I was speaking figuratively, not metaphorically.)

Comment: @DjangoReinhardt I was going by what was said in the article you had linked to in the op. That was all the information I had, and that five-sentence article seemed to suggest the journalist had misinterpreted something. Now that you've provided a new link, with detailed information, everything's become clear, but I don't see how that justifies your high horse riding. (I'm speaking metaphorically, which means figuratively.)

Comment: @TaliaFord I'm sorry if you felt I was getting on my "high horse", but you apparently corrected me based on... I don't know what. I didn't link to a five sentence article, I linked to an audio interview with one of the senior editors at the OED. I guess it bristles when someone brazenly "corrects" you for no reason. But you're right: Metaphorically apparently is synonymous with figuratively -- I didn't realise that -- but now I REALLY don't understand your initial comment :-/