# Are there any pairs of English words that are cognate to each other yet have opposite meanings?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, terminology, antonyms, doublets

Alright, here's the best way I can explain this: if, hypothetically, the word pairs (*love*, *loathe*) and (*friend*, *fiend*) were cognates (i.e. they shared an etymological ancestor), they would be precisely what I'm looking for. These pairs *aren't* cognates, of course, but what I'm trying to get at is that if they *were*, they'd fit my criteria: antonyms that are also cognate to one another.

So, now that that's explained, I have to ask: **does anyone know of a real, *non*-hypothetical duo of words of the type I'm describing?** Also, I realize this is the *English* language board, but if for some reason anyone happens to know of an example of this from a language besides English, please do consider chiming in anyways. Failing that, really any other relevant info or insight would also be a huge help, as I'm pretty much at a loss for leads on this one.

Thanks in advance~

--

*NOTE:* as far as this specific request is concerned, I'm not interested in either:

- contranyms/auto-antonyms (e.g. *fast* can mean both "quick" *and* "unmoving")
- antonyms that only differ in their affix (e.g. *attach*, *detach*; *careful*, *careless*; etc.)

Those two things aside, however, I'm really just looking for any two cognates with contrasting meanings. Whether they're direct, binary opposites (e.g. *true*, *false*) or a more subjective sort of opposites (e.g. *float*, *sink*), I'm all ears. I'd even say feel free even to compare words across different parts of speech (e.g. *alive*, *death*) – just so long as they're English cognates whose definitions clash with each other, *that's* what I want to find at least one veritable example of, if only to say that I can.

***Update! Here's what I have so far:
*black* and *blank* from PIE [*bhel-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*bhel-) (h/t John Lawler)
*shirt* and *skirt* from PIE [*sker-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*sker-) (h/t Xanne)
*potion* and *poison* from PIE [*peh-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/peh%E2%82%83-) / [*po(i)-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*po(i)-) (h/t Matthew Roberts)
*guest* and *host* from PIE [*gʰóstis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/g%CA%B0%C3%B3stis) / [*ghos-ti-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*ghos-ti-) (my own discovery)

Comment: Like sanction? . .Words that have two meanings apparently quite opposite?

Comment: Like _black_ and _blank_, you mean?

Comment: Cognates within a single language, or doublets, may have meanings that are slightly or even totally different. For example, English ward and guard (<PIE *wer-, "to perceive, watch out for") are cognates, as are shirt (garment on top) and skirt (garment on bottom) (<PIE *sker-, "to cut"). In some cases, including this one, one cognate ("skirt") has an ultimate source in another language related to English,[5] but the other one ("shirt") is native.[6]  From Wikipedia, Cognates, section on Doublets.

Comment: Many words are used ironically or sarcastically with an meaning opposite to the original, e.g., “Isn’t *that* cute?”

Comment: Cleave (intransitive) -> (i) to cling or adhere to something - The building cleaved to a narrow strip of rock; (and figurative: The old man cleaved to his wife.) (ii) Transitive: to cut apart using a blow from a sharp instrument. He cleaved the rope with a blow from his sword.

Comment: I assume you would like to exclude word pairs like “clean” and “unclean”.

Comment: See auto-antonyms, though not about cognates. Related to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141845/words-develop-their-opposite) and [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/141845/words-develop-their-opposite) (disclosure: mine).

Comment: Really appreciate all the responses! Pairs like (*black*, *blank*) and (*shirt*, *skirt*) are just the sort of thing I was after, so I'm psyched that posting on here is already paying off. Oh, and since my note at the bottom where I specify sorts of words I'm not interested in might have been a tad vague, I just want to mention that I edited it for clarity.

Comment: Fox, vixen. (male/female)

Comment: "Terrible" and "terrific"; "awful" and "awesome".

Comment: @KyleO'Brien: Came in from ELL SE with almost the same question; in German offhand I know immediately an exact homo-antonym: "fix". Same meaning as in English if used formal, but see here https://www.dwds.de/wb/fix how it logically shifted meaning to mean "quick" in colloquial language.

Answer (score 2):

Just thought of another possible example: *ward* and *guard*. There are quite a few *w-* words in English that have a French *gu-* doublet: *warranty* and *guarantee*, *warden* and *guardian*, *William* and *Guillaume*, *war* and *guerre*. From what I can gather, the Germanic *w-* is the older sound, the *gu-* variations developing later in France, and introduced into English with the Norman invasion.

But for our purpose: *guard* means to defend, whereas a *ward* is someone who is being defended (as in a “ward of court”). Like my previous suggestions, these words aren’t quite antonyms, but they do have opposing meanings. Sort of.

Answer (score 1):

I love this kind of thing. I came across cognates and doublets when studying linguistics at university. I like Phil Sweet’s suggestion of *fox* and *vixen*. I can only think of a couple of suggestions, and I’m not entirely sure they will meet your criteria, Kyle O’Brien, but I’ll post them for what they’re worth (if anyone is still following this thread).

- *potion* / *poison*—my (admittedly rather thin) argument being that *poison* is always something harmful, lethal, whereas *potions* are, or rather were, usually curatives, concocted back in the day by the local white witch of the village to treat some ailment or other;
- *cannabis* / *hemp* / *canvas*—*cannabis* is the plant cultivated for its medicinal and recreational properties; *hemp* is the material made from the plant, which contains no cannabinoids; and *canvas*, a more general term for cloth or fabric, also happens to derive from the same root (Greek: *kannabis*) so I thought I would add it as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for all the suggestions! I must say _potion / poison_ is probably my favorite of the lot. Incidentally, I remember reading that in 
most every other Germanic language, the reflex of Proto-Germanic _*giftiz_ is actually a word for "poison" (German _Gift_, Swedish _gift_, Frisian _jefte_, etc), whereas "gift" obviously has a much different meaning in English. Dutch even has the words _gift_ ("gift") and _gif_ ("poison") as doublets, crazily enough. Funny how poison seems to lend itself to all sorts of lexical weirdness, huh?