# Two Opposite Meanings of 'Cleave'?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

I'm interested in how and why the verb **cleave** has two totally opposite definitions:

> Definition [I.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cleave?q=cleave#cleave) Split or sever (something)
>
> Definiiton [II.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cleave?q=cleave#cleave-2) Adhere strongly to

The referenced website shows the same etymology for both definitions?

Moreover, how can one manage or differentiate these two definitions, to obviate confusion?

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29805/how-does-a-word-come-to-have-two-completely-opposite-meanings?rq=1 suggests different etymologies for the two meanings.

Comment: They're **different words** (according to the best analysis). They have different etymologies, and have arrived at the same spelling and pronunciation by convergent evolution. They are _homonyms_. Wikipedia: In linguistics, a homonym is, in the strict sense, one of a group of words that share the same spelling and pronunciation but may have different meanings. So, the verbs cleave and cleave (dictionaries usually slap on a temporary 1 and 2).

Comment: Doesn't common usage in the 2nd definition require an additional "to" after "cleave", or is that purely biblical?

Answer (score 4):

OED does differentiate the etymologies:

s.v. cleave, *v.<sup>1</sup>*

> 1. a. trans. To part or divide by a cutting blow; to hew asunder; to split.
>
> **Etymology:**  Common Germanic: Old English *clíofan, cléofan,* past tense *cléaf,* plural *clufon,* past participle *clofen* . . .

s.v. cleave, *v.<sup>2</sup>*

> 1. To stick fast or adhere, as by a glutinous surface, *to* . . .
>
> **Etymology:** Old English had two verbs; *clífan* strong (* *cláf*, plural *clifon,* *clifen),* and *clifian, cleofian* weak *(clifode, -od ).*

Biblically enjoined to “[cleave unto his wife](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%202.24&version=AKJV),” poor Henry VIII appears indeed to have got sadly confused between these two senses, though curiously *not* in the case of [wife #4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anne_of_Cleves).

Comment: Thanks. Were you able to answer: Moreover, how can one manage or differentiate these two definitions, to obviate confusion? If not, would you please explain in your answer and not in comments?